# Indirect Addressing Mode

Tags: architecture, mode, operand, addressing

I am currently trying to solve a problem where I am given these criteria:

I believe that I have some of the answers correct but I am confused because the question mentions nothing about an address being stored at address 10 so how can indirect addressing even happen?

**Question**: Where is the corresponding operand given the following addressing modes?

> Assume the address field of an instruction contains the decimal 10.
>   Where is the corresponding operand given the following addressing
>   modes?

1. Immediate addressing: Operand- 10
2. Direct addressing: Operand - 10 -> address
3. Indirect addressing: 10 -> address -> address
4. Register addressing:
5. Register indirect addressing:

Can anybody help me out?

Here's the chart I'm using:
[image]

**Updated where's:**

- Immediate addressing: The corresponding operand is located in the address field of the given memory. In all cases the operand is simply the value in the address field of the given memory location. So in this case the operand value would be 10.
- Direct addressing:  In direct addressing the address field contains the address of the operand. Therefore the corresponding operand is going to be whatever is stored for an operand at memory address 10.
- Indirect addressing: In indirect addressing the contents of memory address 10 are the address to the operand. Therefore the address field of location 10 contains the address to the location holding the operand in its address field.
- Register addressing: In register addressing the address field of memory location 10 holds an address to a register instead of another memory address. The corresponding operand is found inside the contents of the register.
- Register indirect addressing: Register indirect addressing is very similar to register addressing because memory location 10 also holds an address to a location containing its operand, however; the difference is that the address could be to a register or to a memory location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purposes of the question, assume that an address **is** stored in memory location 10.  After all, this is what a real CPU does.  If the address turns out to be invalid, the CPU will likely send a signal or terminate the offending process.

Assume memory contains:

```
10: 100
20: 200
100: 1000
```

and register #10 contains: `20`

The answers are:

1. 10: The operand is contained in the instruction itself.
2. 100
3. 1000
4. 20: The register itself contains the operand.  The register number is encoded in the instruction.
5. 200: The register contains the address of the operand.

Comment: So when answering these questions I'm looking for more of an answer like, "The address at memory location 10."?

Comment: Please clarify what question(s) you really want answered by editing your question post.

Comment: I have just now. Thanks.

Comment: My question asks where, not what, however;are you just choosing arbitrary numbers based on what the memory address is?

Comment: Given the 'what' (which I gave), you can determine the 'where' since each value is in a unique place.

Comment: I have updated my wheres on my original post. Could you take a look at them and tell me how they sound. Thank you by the way.

Comment: 1, 4 and 5 aren't quite right.  See what I wrote.   And the best 'thank you' is an upvote :).